# Drupal 7 entityforms module: How to get value of a field with php?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-entities

I am using the entityform module to capture some user submitted data http://drupal.org/project/entityform

I need to pull in some of the entity field values into one of my templates. I was trying to do this with some code that works for regular node fields..

```
<?php echo $node->field_title[$node->language]['value']; ?>
```

I've tried..

```
<?php echo $entity->field_title[$node->language]['value']; ?>
```

But that doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Should that be <?php echo $entity->field_title[**$entity**->language]['value']; ?> instead?

Comment: Does this help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27293/programmatically-get-field-values

Comment: I don't think it helps :( Looks like that is just for getting the value of a node's field. I need to get the value of a field from an entity.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $field_data = field_get_items('entityform',$entityform,'field_title');
    echo render(field_view_value('entityform',$entityform,'field_title',$field_data));
?>
```

[field_get_items documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) , [field_view_value documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7)

Comment: Getting the following error.. Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in include() (line 1 of /home/mrktspac/public_html/nvoy/sites/all/themes/boilerplate/templates/entityform.tpl.php).

Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in /home/mrktspac/public_html/nvoy/modules/field/field.module on line 801

Comment: ok then, your field is not an array, I have updated my code example. You may need to pass your field differently to the field_view_value depending on your field.  Or you can echo the raw value from the $field_data array and forget about using field_view_value (but that raw value will not be sanatized)

Comment: This is essentially the right answer...a quick look at the module code suggests you should replace `'entity_type'` with `'entityform'` and `$entity` with `$entityform` and that should work

Comment: @Clive Yeah I was just providing a more general answer, 'entity_type' and $entity are just general variables.Dustin, I have updated my code so it is more specific to the entityform module you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the entityform_id of a submission, you can load it like this:

```
entity_load('entityform', $entityform_id);
```